# How to show that if $\neg b = a \land d$ then $a \land \neg b = \neg b$ and $b \land \neg a = \neg a$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I'm new to boolean algebra and am having trouble proving the following simple theorem. Many thanks for any help.

If  $\neg b = a \land d$ then $a \land \neg b = \neg b$ and $b \land \neg a = \neg a$.

Here's how I've been going about solving it:

$\neg b = a \land d$

$a \land \neg b = a \land (a \wedge d)$

$a \land \neg b = a \land d$

$a \land \neg b = \neg b$

This proves the first expression (I think?).

Then for the second expression we start with the first one.

$a \land \neg b = \neg b$

$\neg (a \land \neg b) = b$

$\neg a \lor b = b$

... and here I get stuck?

How do I get from $\neg a \lor b = b$ to $b \land \neg a = \neg a$ ?

Now if we think of this in terms of sets, you can see how  $A^{c} \cup B = B$ can only hold true if $A^{c} \subseteq B$ and hence it can be seen how $b \land \neg a = \neg a$ may hold. But I'm not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part works fine.

For the second, the following will work, but I don't know what your axiom set and rules of inference say.

```
assumption           1 ¬b=(a∧d) 
introduce "V" in 1   2 (a V ¬b)=(aV(a∧d)).
2 (xV(x^y))=x        3 (a V ¬b)=a
3 ¬¬a=a              4 ¬¬(a V ¬b)=¬¬a
4 ¬(aVb)=(¬a^¬b)     5 ¬(¬a∧¬¬b)=¬¬a
canceling ¬'s in 5   6 (¬a∧¬¬b)=¬a
6 ¬¬a=a              7 (¬a∧b)=¬a
7 (x^y)=(y^x)        8 (b∧¬a)=¬a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) Is it necessary to use the double negation in step 4? Can't we just negate both sides once?

Comment: @user1200428 No, it's not necessary to use double negation as I did.  Since, (a V ¬b)=a, and ¬a=¬a, we could just replace the left "a" in  ¬a=¬a with (a V ¬b) and thus obtain ¬(a V ¬b)=¬a, and complete the proof from there.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about Boolean algebra is that there isn't always a shortcut (unless some very monumental mathematical results manifest to surprise us all).

In your first question, you found a nice shortcut by applying $a \land \dots$ to both sides.  But sometimes you just have to write out the truth tables and nothing is faster.  It's more important to know how to do this the slow systematic way than it is to memorize the shortcuts.

So to do the second question in the most direct fashion, just check all 8 cases of $a$, $b$, and $d$:

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{T}{\color{blue}{\text{T}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{F}{\color{red}{\text{F}}}
\begin{array} {ccc|c|c|c}
a & b & d & \lnot b = a \land d & b \land \lnot a = \lnot a & (\lnot b = a \land d) \rightarrow (b \land \lnot a = \lnot a) \\
\T & \T & \T &  \F   & \T  & \T\\
\T & \T & \F &  \F   & \T  & \T\\
\T & \F & \T &  \T   & \T  & \T\\
\T & \F & \F &  \F   & \T  & \T\\
\F & \T & \T &  \T   & \T  & \T\\
\F & \T & \F &  \T   & \T  & \T\\
\F & \F & \T &  \F   & \F  & \T\\
\F & \F & \F &  \F   & \F  & \T\\
\end{array}
$$

So you can see that the implication always holds.

Comment: It is not clear to me from the question whether he is proving the identity in an arbitrary Boolean algebra, but that is the appearance I take from it.

Comment: Do you think that he might be working with a set of axioma which are only a subset of the axioma of a complete Boolean Algebra?  That would be cruel way to misteach something.

Comment: I think it's relatively common to use the axioms saying that a Boolean algebra is a distributive lattice with greatest and least elements in which each element has a complement, and then expect students to prove Boolean identities from those axioms without using truth tables.

Comment: It isn't true that truth tables have to get written out in any case.  Sure, they might work out as easier or faster, but if we have an identity which holds for a Boolean Algebra, then it can get derived from an axiom set with the rules/axioms from first order predicate calculus with equality.  And we don't know that he's even referencing the two-valued model of Boolean Algebras or has proved that if an equation holds in the two-valued model it holds in any model.  There do exist concrete Boolean Algebras such as ({1,2,5,7,10,14,35,70), gcd, lcm, (70/x)) where (70/x) is the complement of x.

Comment: I learned Boolean Algebra in engineering digital design classes, where the purpose is to use and apply it, so my vocabulary may be a bit different than the majority of users on these forums.  In my background, "Boolean" means 2 valued the way Boole did it.  Your second sentence I think depends on definitions, some logics exclude $\lnot \lnot x = x$.  Thanks for the comments, I'll keep the difference terms in mind.

Comment: @Doug Yes, with sufficient axioms, you don't have to write out truth tables, but unless amazing complexity results are found, then in general truth tables are no slower than searching for the correct application of axiom.  So rather than conditioning a student to think that there must be shortcuts, I would prefer that they learn the systematic approach first.  A student should never approach a problem like this and be unable to solve it at all.  Slow is better than nothing IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this: by calculation.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
$We are given that
$$
\tag 0 \lnot b \;\equiv\; a \land d
$$
For the first part, we start at the most complex side, and try to simplify $\;a \land \lnot b\;$:
$$\calc
a \land \lnot b
\calcop\equiv{using $\ref 0$ -- the only thing we know}
a \land a \land d
\calcop\equiv{logic: simplify}
a \land d
\calcop\equiv{using $\ref 0$ -- to get us to our goal}
\lnot b
\endcalc$$
This proves the first part.

Now the second part can be done in a similar fashion, but you will also need to use DeMorgan and absorption.